# Blender 2.76b wont install. Error Message pops up

Tags: installation

I've been trying to install the latest build of blender on my PC but every time I try I get this error message [image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Move the file to a location like Desktop before running the Setup.

Comment: I did that. Still didn't work.

Comment: the error is really Windows/Explorer telling you "The cabinet file 'media1.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used"  -- it's worth googling.

Comment: I just tried it on another computer and I ran into the same issue, so I think it's safe to assume it's a problem with the installer and not my machine.

Comment: Which operating systems?  The point i'd like to counter with is those installers are used by at least 500k people, using all kinds of versions of windows. The installer expects certain components to be present, if it doesn't find those or they are corrupt it will throw a warning message like this one.  Are you downloading the .exe to the desktop then double-clicking it or did you press Run in the downloaded files in the browser?

Comment: make sure you are installing a version that matches your Operating system, i.e. a 64 bit version for a 64bit OS or 32 bit for a 32bit OS. Check for the system type in the properties on "My Computer" or on Control Panel->System and Security->System

Comment: I managed to install the 32-bit version. For me, the problem was with the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem using chrome, trying all the available packages, downloading to various places including desktop, and running after saving.

I switched to Windows 10 Microsoft Edge browser and was unable to download the installer.  However I was able to download the zip file correctly and run blender from there.

Moral of story, keep trying different things until something works....

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://download.blender.org/release/

Download the compressed zip file instead of the .msi. Then extract the folder. That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem using chrome. I changed my browser and I successfully installed it. So I guess you should try another browser. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unless previous browser was downloading corrupted files every time (one should search really hard to find browser like that) this answer can't be related to the problem.